# Add offset value to time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I felt like this should be easy but I'm not finding answer. The query below will give me the current date/time in California and represent it as UTC with a timezone offset (currently -08:00):

```
select getdate() at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time'
```

I simply want to apply the offset and get a timestamp showing the current *local* time and then drop the offset. I feel like there should be a way to achieve this without having to pick through it with string and date functions. For example, I want to go from

```
2021-11-24 18:03:41.190 -08:00
```

to

```
2021-11-24 10:03:41.190
```

Is there a succinct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `AT TIME ZONE` on a value that *isn't* a `datetimeoffset` it's assumed that the value is at the time zone you are converting it to.

Instead, therefore, you could nest the `AT TIME ZONE` clauses. If you did do this though, I would also suggest using `SYSUTCDATE` rather than `GETDATE` (which returns the local time to the host, which could be **any** timezone).

```sql
SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time';
```

Though really, just use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET` to start with; then you just need one `AT TIME ZONE` as the RDBMS already knows what timezone the value is for.

```sql
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f6573d2a304c4ddf8a11e24af32e2cf)

Comment: Okay that's good. GETDATE() was just for my example though. I need to convert datetime's that are stored in UTC _without_ the offset. So it looks like this might work:
select MyDatetimeFieldInUTC AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' from x

Comment: So just convert back to datetime after calculating the date/time at the specified time zone.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @myDateTime datetime = '2021-11-24 21:35:25.984';  --UTC time
 Select cast(@myDateTime At Time Zone 'UTC' At Time Zone 'Pacific Standard Time' As datetime);
```

Or - you can just apply the desired offset and convert back to datetime

```
 Select cast(switchoffset(@myDateTime, '-08:00') As datetime)
```

The problem with using switchoffset is that it isn't DST aware and would need to be changed to use a different offset value.  If you change the date above to October - the PST time would be 14:35:25.983 but the second calculation still returns 13:35:25.983